# Rails 4 Generating Invalid Column Names

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a fairly simple query to return the first record in a many-to-many relation or create one if it doesn't exist.

```
UserCategorization.where(category_id: 3, user_id: 5).first_or_create
```

My model looks like:

```
class UserCategorization < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :category

    self.primary_key = [:user_id, :category_id]
end
```

However it generates an invalid column name in the SQL:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: user_categorizations.[:user_id, :category_id]:

SELECT  "user_categorizations".* FROM "user_categorizations"  WHERE
"user_categorizations"."category_id" = 3 AND "user_categorizations"."user_id" = 5
ORDER BY "user_categorizations"."[:user_id, :category_id]" ASC LIMIT 1
```

If I remove `self.primary_key = [:user_id, :category_id]` from the model, it can retrieve the record correctly but cannot save because it doesn't know what to use in the WHERE clause:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: user_categorizations.: 

UPDATE "user_categorizations" SET "score" = ? 
WHERE "user_categorizations"."" IS NULL
```

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Yeah, but see how it's saying the column name is the exact string `[:user_id, :category_id]`? It could be due to the `self.primary_key` set perhaps.

Comment: Why are you explicitly setting the primary key in the way you are?  Rails will automatically infer the primary keys of the models that are related to.  Are you trying to make a compound primary key?

Comment: Ah so when I remove that it can retrieve it correctly, but when I try and change a variable and save, it tries to update without a primary key: `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: user_categorizations.: UPDATE "user_categorizations" SET "score" = ? WHERE "user_categorizations"."" IS NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

I think one of these two suggestions will work:

First, try adding the following migration:

```
add_index :user_categorizations, [:user_id, :category_id]
```

Make sure to keep  `self.primary_key = [:user_id, :category_id]` in your `UserCategorization` model.

If that doesn't work, destroy the  `UserCategorization` table and run this migration:

```
def change
    create_table :user_categorizations do |t|
      t.references :user
      t.references :category
      t.timestamps
    end
end
```

`references` are new to Rails 4.  They add a foreign key and index to the specified columns.

Good Luck!

Comment: The index didn't seem to fix it. Do I need to use `id: false` for the join table? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think id: false will work. I would try my second suggestion.  Its new for Rails 4.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like Rails 4 ActiveRecord doesn't do composite keys very well so many-to-many models create the issues above. I fixed it by using this extension to ActiveRecord: http://compositekeys.rubyforge.org/

Comment: that sounds odd, ActiveRecord can only handle many-to-many partly?

Comment: It is rather odd. The problem is my many-to-many relation was also a model with two composite keys and Rails didn't handle that properly.